# Blank page after bibliography

Tags: header-footer, blank-page

I want to create a blank page after the bibliography which has no page number or any other things I've defined in fancyhdr. Just a blank page, where I can input some text. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, putting

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
...some text...
```

should work.

Comment: Yes it does. I want to have a title on this page without any numbering in front of it. Is it possible to modify the \section command?

Comment: Use `\section*`.

Comment: GREAT, that worked really well!